# Python virtual environment not working any more after change to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, python, pip, virtualenv

Up to now I used on my computer mainly Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, a few weeks ago I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a free partition.

Now I transferred my `/home/juergen` directory from the 16.04 partition to the new 18.04 partition (I stayed with the default single partition scheme) by doing the following

1. mounting the old (16.04) partition on new `/mnt`, then
2. `cd /mnt/home`
3. doing `tar -cvzf /home/jb.tgz juergen` to pack all old `$HOME` stuff
   into `jb.tgz`.
4. Finally I did `cd /home` and `tar -xvzf jb.tgz`

(I add this information although not directly connected with my question proper just to 'set the stage')

Now my actual problem: I have in my home directory a large python virtual environment from which I used to run jupyter-lab and other applications:

```
juergen@regulus:~/venv/python3sci$ ls
bin  etc  include  lib  lib64  man  pip-selfcheck.json  pyvenv.cfg  share  software
juergen@regulus:~/venv/python3sci$ cat pyvenv.cfg 
home = /usr/bin
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.5.2
```

But I can not use it anymore:

```
juergen@regulus:~/venv/python3sci$ cd bin
juergen@regulus:~/venv/python3sci/bin$ . activate
(python3sci) juergen@regulus:~/venv/python3sci/bin$ jupyter-lab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/juergen/venv/python3sci/bin/jupyter-lab", line 5, in <module>
    from jupyterlab.labapp import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyterlab'
(python3sci) juergen@regulus:~/venv/python3sci/bin$ pip -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/juergen/venv/python3sci/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
(python3sci) juergen@regulus:~/venv/python3sci/bin$ pip3 -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/juergen/venv/python3sci/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
(python3sci) juergen@regulus:~/venv/python3sci/bin$
```

The python and pip entries in virtual environment `bin`

```
(python3sci) juergen@regulus:~/venv/python3sci/bin$ ls -la python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 juergen juergen  7 Nov 10  2019 python -> python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 juergen juergen 16 Nov 10  2019 python3 -> /usr/bin/python3
(python3sci) juergen@regulus:~/venv/python3sci/bin$ ls -la pip*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 juergen juergen 245 Nov 10  2019 pip
-rwxrwxr-x 1 juergen juergen 245 Nov 10  2019 pip3
-rwxrwxr-x 1 juergen juergen 245 Nov 10  2019 pip3.5
```

I googled quite some time for the error messages above but could not find an answer which seemed promising to help in my case.

*Question*: *So what can I do to get my virtual environment working again?*

(If you need additional output from my system I will edit it in this question on demand).

Many thanks in advance!

NEW INFO: The following question

[Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512025/update-existing-virtualenv-to-use-python-3-6/44529211)

exactly fitted to my problem. Seemingly it is impossible to hope for a simple upgrade with some magical python invocation, as (so said there) python3.5 (the 16.04 standard) and python3.6 (the new standard one in 18.04) are not even binary compatible any more.

So the solution advised was to create with `pip freeze > req.txt` (in the functioning virtual environment in my 16.04 installation) a list `req.txt` of required packages and then with `pip install -r req.txt` (in a freshly created virtual environment in the 18.04 installation) do a reinstall of all necessary dependencies.

It worked for me 99% well, only my most sought after project `pymesh` I can not recompile by now - it has tons of dependencies and its user manual gives no install workflow with pip alone so I expected the trouble that came as waited for.

Comment: By taking the old 16.04 home dir contents and putting them in the 18.04 version home dir you carried over configs from 16.04 that were in the home dir that 18.04 probly did not like.